# Looping through data to find statistics and assigning them to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've greatly appreciated the help I've received on this so far, it's been really useful. As stated in a previous post, I'm working on a project for university crunching a bunch of stream level data that was collected on a daily basis and looks like this in a .csv:

```
 ID Year        DD  Apr  May    Jun  Jul    Aug      Sep    Oct
08HB089 2000    1   3.25 3.83   2.34 1.05   0.273   0.092   0.045
08HB089 2000    2   5.18 3.3    2.6  1.09   0.225   0.081   0.04
08HB089 2000    3   5.5  3.33   2.92 0.93   0.186   0.054   0.036
08HB089 2000    4   4.98 2.53   3.33 0.804  0.153   0.041   0.033
```

And so forth for another 400 lines. What I've done so far is create a script that does the following:

1. Selects the desired year ("2000")
2. Offsets the selection two to the right so that the values for April (or whatever month) are selected.
3. Computes the average and standard deviation and assigns them to a cell.

See code below:

```
 Sub StatMakersub(Rng1 As Range)
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Object
    Dim InQuestion As Range
    Dim SelAvg As Variant
    Dim SelSD As Variant
    Dim L As Integer
    Dim Year As Integer

For L = 2 To 17
    Year = 2000
    For Each Cell In Rng1
    If Cell.Value = Year Then
            If MyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set MyRange = Range(Cell.Address)
            Else
                Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Range(Cell.Address))
                MyRange.Select
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("08HB089_daily_Flow_Tab")
                    Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
                    Set InQuestion = Selection
                    SelAvg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(InQuestion)
                    Range(L, 15).Value = SelAvg
                    SelSD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(InQuestion)
                    Range(L, 16).Value = SelSD
            Year = Year + 1
End Sub
```

I'm quite  new at coding if you can't tell :). What I want to do now is add looping capabilities to the function so I don't have to do it all by hand. As you can see, I've tried with a for loop above but I keep getting syntax errors. If anyone could help me figure out how to add looping capabilities that searches for a specific year, finds the data, and calculates its statistics into a cell (say, L2), then does the next for the next year (2001) and puts those stats in the next cell (L3), I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You are not on the wrong way. Try some more. Complete `for loop`s and `If block`s. First I think the variables which are to be passed this sub is not a `range` but may be year and month.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you need to mark the end of the code that is to be looped with the "next" command. In this case, you should use "Next L"

That said, unless you're just doing this as a project to learn VBA, I think you can get all the functionality you need from a Pivot Table. Simply put, a pivot table lets you manipulate data that can be grouped differently by a number of different columns. I would say more, but there are tons of good tutorials out there that can probably teach you better than I could.

Comment: Oh wow thank you, this is saving a lot of time. I was using VBA for cleaning up my data and thought I would just keep going with it, this is much easier. 1000 thank yous.